# XAML Control array for static number of combo boxes

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I would like an array of 10 combo boxes on a wpf form.

The ItemsSource of the combo boxes are identical - an ObservableCollection of selectable Items.

Each Selected Item will bound to an item in a different ObservableCollection, imaginatively called 'SelectedItems'..

What is the best way to do the array? I could of course have 10 separate combo boxes but this would be not very elegant..

I don't think an ItemsControl template is what I'm after as the number of combo boxes is static.

Thanks

Joe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you right, you have 10 ComboBoxes with the same item list, but different data sources

In that case, I could create a common style for the ComboBox which sets the common properties such as `ItemsSource` (and `SelectedItem` if the binding is the same for all items), and then actually create the individual ComboBoxes on the form as needed.

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <!-- Set the binding to wherever your ItemsSource resides. In this
                 case,I'm binding to a static class called Lists and a static 
                 property called ComboBoxItems -->
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" 
                    Value="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Lists.ComboBoxItems}}" />

            <!-- Only use this setter if your binding is the same everywhere -->
            <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <ComboBox DataContext="{Binding Item1}" />
    <ComboBox DataContext="{Binding Item2}" />
    <ComboBox DataContext="{Binding Item3}" />
    <ComboBox DataContext="{Binding Item4}" />
    <ComboBox DataContext="{Binding Item5}" />
    <ComboBox DataContext="{Binding Item6}" />
    <ComboBox DataContext="{Binding Item7}" />
    <ComboBox DataContext="{Binding Item8}" />
    <ComboBox DataContext="{Binding Item9}" />
    <ComboBox DataContext="{Binding Item10}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Of course, if the DataSource for your ComboBoxes CAN be put in a collection, it is preferred that they are and that you use an `ItemsControl` to display the ComboBoxes

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding }"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Lists.ComboBoxItems}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thanks Rachel - 'If I understand you right, you have 10 ComboBoxes with the same item list, but different data sources'  - yes each combo box will be bound to a separate item in a 'SelectedItems' ObservableCollection.. but the answer to 'if the DataSource for your ComboBoxes CAN be put in a collection' is also yes.. sorry for the confusion - so you would recommend ItemsControl?

Comment: @Joe.Net Yes, I would definitely recommend an `ItemsControl` in your situation. Based on what you said in your original question, you can bind the `ItemsControl.ItemCollection` to `SelectedItems`, and just set the ComboBox `SelectedItem="{Binding }"` on your ComboBoxes to bind the selected item to the item in the collection. Since you're using an ItemTemplate, you don't need to create a separate style for your ComboBoxes

Answer (score 2):

> Each Selected Item will bound to an item in a different ObservableCollection, imaginatively called 'SelectedItems'..

Given that you're effectively binding to a collection, I would do an ItemsControl template, and just treat it that way.  Unless you want to customize the layout (ie: these won't be arranged together in the View), that will simplify the design, even if the number of items is always "static".

If you want to have the items arranged separately on the View, then just having 10 combo boxes may be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Reed.  'Given that you're effectively binding to a collection, I would do an ItemsControl template' - Each Combo box will be empty on Start up - only when an item is selected will this be added to the ObservableCollection - is your advise still to go with the ItemsControl?  (I was thinking about putting the combo boxes into a panel, so they are ordered (so to speak))

Comment: @Joe.Net: Yes - though "empty on Start up" will probably need to be "null on startup" - with a value being set appropriately when selected.  The OC<T> will likely need to be initialized with 10 empty values... But yes, this is how I'd approach it.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I think an `ItemsControl` which has an `ItemTemplate` which constructs each `ComboBox` *is* the way to go! Are you always going to have exactly 10 of these?

From an MVVM perspective, I can imagine a parent View Model which has a collection of selection view models. Each selection view model will have the list of items that can be selected, and the currently selected item. This view model will easily bind to your view.

Comment: Thanks Colin - yes 10 - but this will change in the future - but I wanted an easy and elegant way to change it - hence my Control Array thinking..

Answer (score -1):

Not knowing why you need this... which would probably be important in deciding how to do this... here is my stab at it.

Why not design the UI, give each ComboBox a name, create a List and Add each into that List at runtime?

Comment: yuck - this is not terribly easy to maintain if you want to add / remove combo-boxes, or change their style, or ...

Comment: Indeed, but it is exactly what the original poster asked for... if he wanted something maintainable, we're all pretty capable of doing that as well. I don't think it deserves a downvote, though.